# Augmented reality in iphone using wikitude

Tags: iphone

I am using wikitude API for augmented reality in my iPhone app. But I got stuck in implementing that in my application.

I am having one button in my one View on clicking of which I want to open the Wikitude AR view but I am not able to add it over that view.
As in Sample application provided by Wikitude this wikitudeAR view is added over the Main window but in my application I want to add the view([wikitudeAR Start]) over my view like(self.view addSubview:[wikitudeAR Start]) which is not working.
Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code, in which you are adding it as subview

Comment: i've the same problem..also when i remove the camera controller view from the main window, this hides the top status bar...

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem

after you have added wikitude to the subview, call the following method

```
[wikitudeAR show];
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the Wikitude View as a subView of the key Window.
Then, you can show or hide it using the "show" and "hide" methods.

The code is:

```
- (void) verificationDidSucceed {
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:[wikitudeAR start]];
}
```